# ASCIIZ string ending with a zero byte

Tags: string, assembly, x86, dos

I was writing an Assembly level program to create a file.

```
.model small
.data
 Fn db "test" 
.code
mov ax,@data 
mov ds,ax

mov CX,00
lea DX,Fn

mov ah,3ch
int 21h

Mov ah,4ch
Into 21h
End
```

Although program had no errors, but file was not created, so I searched the internet for getting the reason.

Then I found ASCIIZ.

So I replaced data segment with

```
.data
Fn db "test", 0
```

It worked.

Why do we need to use ASCIIZ and why can't a normal string be used to create a file?

Comment: Without knowing what operating system you're using, it's quite hard to say, but I'd guess the routines you're trying to use want a "normal" **C** string, which **must** be terminated by a 0 byte. Your original code doesn't guarantee what comes after "test," so it very well could be anything, including a character illegal for your filesystem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: Because if you read the [documentation regarding `int 21h`](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah3c) with `ah = 3ch` it tells you that the file name string must terminate in a zero. Otherwise, how will it know where the end of the string is? And `Fn db "test"` doesn't automatically zero terminate a string. It must be explicit.

Comment: @Joe: INT 21h is a typical MS-DOS (and derivative) system call.

Comment: I'm using windows, and I understood what you are trying to tell. But now I have new problem. When I tried deleting the same file by replacing the mov ah,3ch with mov ah,41h, the output I got was "Illegle path". What should I do?

Comment: Where was your file created? In EMU8086, files are created inside of emu8086/MyBuild. Check permissions on the folder where your file was created. Are you sure your file still there?

Comment: I use MASM on dosbox as my windows is 64-bit, MASM doesn't support it. I changed the permissions also, file still exists.

Comment: Try the full path :  Fn db "c:\mycompiler\myproject\test.txt", 0 . Let's see if full path allows you to delete it.

Comment: You can also try other assemblers that don't need virtual machines, like EMU8086 (for 32 bits programs, doesn't support EAX) or GUI Turbo Assembler x64 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/guitasm8086/).

Comment: Giving the full path also didn't work, this is the full code<br/> `.model small<br/>
.data<br/>
 filename db "D:\MASM\test.txt",0<br/>

.code<br/>
 mov ax,@data<br/>
 mov ds,ax<br/>
 
 
 lea dx,filename<br/>
 
 mov ah,41h<br/>
 int 21h<br/>
 
 mov ah,4ch<br/>
 int 21h<br/> 
 end`

Comment: Aside: always read the documentation. Following comment from @lurker, print string to `stdin` Int 21h function 09h requires the string to be terminated by a dollar `$`.

Comment: Khacho, I would try another assembler, EMU8086 is small and easy to use, download it, install it, open it, copy-paste your little code and press F5 to run.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I tried the EMU8086 and I was able to delete the file using it. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Is that final `into` instruction in your actual program as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have multiple string into your `.data` section:

```
Fn db "test" 
s1 db "aaa"
s2 db "bbb"
```

When you will compile it, `.data` section will have all 3 strings in it, one after other:

```
0x74 0x65 0x73 0x74 0x61 0x61 0x61 0x62 0x62 0x62
```

which is binary representation for `testaaabbb`.

There must be a way for functions to figure out where first string ends and the second begins. This "marker" is 0x00 byte ( "\x00" ), this is also know as "null byte terminated string" or ASCIIZ, that way you can know where your string is ending:

```
Fn db "test",0
s1 db "aaa",0x00 ; is the same
s2 db "bbb\x00" ; still same thing
```

now your `.data` section will looks like this

```
0x74 0x65 0x73 0x74 0x00 0x61 0x61 0x61 0x00 0x62 0x62 0x62 0x00
```

which is `test\x00aaa\x00bbb\x00`and now you have a delimited between strings so when you provide the starting address of your string to a function, it will know where exactly your string ends.

Comment: You forgot the NUL byte after `"bbb"` when you listed the contents of the data section at the end.